# Rebuilding an 'Asp.Net' website in Drupal

Tags: drupal-6

A website is built in Asp.Net. I need to migrate it to Drupal,i.e, build it in Drupal. It has got a lot of content and demands many 'blocks' on the front page. It would be very tedious to have those many blocks in drupal as it would take a lot of time to load the content whenever the page reloads.

Is there a way out to manage such huge data while building that website in Drupal.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any features on that page that couldn't be accomplished with Drupal. The "time to load" issue you mention could be alleviated by using one of the variety of cache methods available in Drupal, such as the [Boost](https://drupal.org/project/boost) module. If you're concerned about performance, I'd recommend checking out the [Pressflow project](http://pressflow.org/), especially coupled with [Varnish](http://www.varnish-cache.org/), a reverse proxy cache.

Comment: Thank you for responding. Will try out the modules suggested by you. I would get back to you if there are any further queries.